# The SEO company wants me to put in h1 tags - where do I do that in the Magento shopping cart?

Tags: seo

My SEO company wants me to put in the **h1 tags** to help with the Search engine rankings. Where can I put these in? Can I put them in using the admin panel or do I have to put them into the actual code?

Thank you so much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

You can tell him that he can rest assured that you have already taken care of this. The H1 tag is in the shopping cart page already. So unless you used a theme that removed it, you should be all set.

On a separate note, you don't really want SEO for that page. The cart is customer specific and should be empty when crawled by search engines.

This is the line for the `<h1>` in your theme.

[image]

Comment: BTW, if you want to make sure the H1 is on the page, select "view source" from your browser and search for: "<h1" ... without quotes

Comment: hi - that's the thing - they claim there are NO h1 tags there...where exactly do I put these? I have to put them on the front page and also individual categories pages...

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Looking at the source for your page I can see the H1 tag. https://www.evernote.com/l/AfqAOQWH9jdLQ66DACDfWXq2BGprd2GHEG4B/image.png

Comment: but it says: "shopping cart" the h1 tag suppose to say:
Flowers Denver Metro, Aurora, Centennial, Cherry Hills, Englewood, Highlands Ranch, Lakewood, Littleton, Lone Tree – 5280flowers.com
AND the Title tag (which I think it does):
Flowers Denver, CO | Florist & Flower Arrangements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23999/discussion-between-daniel-smith-and-allysin).

Comment: I have updated the original response.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping - I am in the chat room you started if you have a moment...thanx again! ;-)

Comment: I modified the file and Cleared ALL Cache, re-indexed but it did not work - it does not show in the h1 of the front page...

Comment: I'm back in the chat

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the pages that you are editing. If you are modifying cms pages or blocks then you can make the modifications through the magento admin interface under the CMS menu. Otherwise you will need to go and edit you template files and make the changes there.

Comment: hi - that's the thing - they claim there are NO h1 tags there...where exactly do I put these? I have to put them on the front page and also individual categories pages...

Comment: Without knowing more information about your home page, my answer is a blind guess, I would say look for a CMS page record for home. 

With regards to category pages, I am assuming they say you need to add that tags to the category titles. To do this you will need to edit the file
_app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/category/view.phtml_

Your package and theme can be found in the backed under **system** > **configuration** > **General** > **Design**. There are two sections, package and theme for the respective values.